# How can I plot a complex numered list into complex plane?

Tags: python, matplotlib, complex-numbers

```
[(-1.9984848484848483-0.05681818181818188j),
 (-1.9984848484848483-0.03409090909090917j),
 (-1.9984848484848483-0.011363636363636243j),
 (-1.9984848484848483+0.011363636363636465j),
 (-1.9984848484848483+0.03409090909090917j)]
```

How can I plot something like this into the complex plane in python using matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the list into a numpy array, then scatter plot with `real` and `imag` components:

```
zs = np.array([(-1.9984848484848483-0.05681818181818188j),
 (-1.9984848484848483-0.03409090909090917j),
 (-1.9984848484848483-0.011363636363636243j),
 (-1.9984848484848483+0.011363636363636465j),
 (-1.9984848484848483+0.03409090909090917j)])

plt.scatter(zs.real, zs.imag)
```

Resulting in:

[image]